# Is it possible to create an if statement involving buttons?

Tags: javascript, button, if-statement

In my program there are multiple buttons, and what I want to happen is for there to be a function that would only run if all of them were pressed. I was thinking of having an if statement which would require all three buttons to be clicked, and then the function would run. Is this possible?

Comment: Store 3 separate variables. Each time one of the buttons is pressed, set the value of that button's variable to `true`, then check if all three variables are `true`, and if so, run your custom function. This could also be done with an array with three values instead of three variables.

Comment: Yes. If i want more help you should show us some code.

Comment: Thanks. Can I see some code that would represent that?

Comment: No. This site well help you debug, fix, and understand code, but this site is not here to get someone else to write the code for you. Try writing it yourself in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and see how far you can get. If you get stuck, *then* come back here, show us what you've got so far, and we might be able to help you.

Comment: If you want some help, show us how far you can go.

Comment: you can do this using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if I fully understood that, but If you want to check if all of the buttons are pressed. First you will have to make a function to know if the button is pressed or not then you make and if statement like the next example:

```
if(button1.isPressed() && button2.isPressed() && button3.isPressed && button4.isPressed){
    // Do whathever you want
};
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

In the future, you should have some work to share when you ask a question like this. However, here's a way of implementing it. I've commented it heavily so that you can see what I've done, as I'm guessing you're new to javascript at least.

```js
//array to hold whether each button has been clicked
var buttonsClicked = [false, false, false]; 

//function to check if any button has not been clicked
function allButtonsClicked() {
  //loop through 0 to the highest index in the array (at the moment, this will be 2)
  for (i = 0; i < buttonsClicked.length; i++) {
    if (!buttonsClicked[i])
      return false; //return false if the value is false, no need to keep looping
  }
  return true; //return true if the loop completes without returning false
}

//function to handle button clicks. Takes an argument which will be hardcoded into the input tag
function buttonClicked(button) {
  //set the specified button to true
  buttonsClicked[button] = true;
  if (allButtonsClicked()) //call the function to check if all buttons are clicked
    alert('All buttons have been clicked'); //if true, do the alert
}

function resetButtons() { //function to set all the "click states" in the array back to false
  for (i = 0; i < buttonsClicked.length; i++) { //again, loop from 0 to the highest index in the array
    buttonsClicked[i] = false; //set each button to false
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Zero" onclick="buttonClicked(0);" />
<input type="button" value="One" onclick="buttonClicked(1);" />
<input type="button" value="Two" onclick="buttonClicked(2);" />
<br />
<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="resetButtons();" />
```